# Trying to write to a file, but I get an error saying that write needs a file object not a string

Tags: python

Thanks for all the feedback, error is now fixed.

I am trying to use this code to write to a file.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
ctime = str(datetime.now())
try:
    open("pyth_log.txt", "w")
    file.write("pyth_log.txt")
    file.write("-------")
    file.write("LOG")
    file.write(ctime)
    file.write("-------")
    file.close()
except:
    print("Unable to open file")
    raise
```

Error I get:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'
```

I have also tried to run the code with "pyth_log.txt" not in quotes but then it gives me the error:

```
NameError: name 'pyth_log' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you try using the object returned by `open()`?

Comment: You are calling `file.write()` but you never defined `file`.

Comment: @pstatix: `file` is defined, it just isn't what they want it to be.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Where is the variable name `file` defined?

Comment: @pstatix `file` is a built in type, similar to `open`

Comment: BTW -- if you're doing `from datetime import datetime`, then you shouldn't also run `import datetime`. Use one or the other, depending on what exactly you want the name `datetime` to point to.

Comment: @pstatix: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams OP is not using the `file` built type in this case. They are trying to call the `write()` method of a file object. Your link is only applicable to Python 2, the `file()` function no longer exists in Python 3.

Comment: @pstatix: Just because it's not what they want doesn't mean they're not using it. That it exists shows that they're using 2.x.

Comment: @Wondercricket If the OP wants to call `write()` without using the returned file object they would need to call `open("pyth_log.txt", 'w').write("LOG")`. Here they are trying to use `write()` which is a member function a file object (in this case, the one that should be returned by `open()`); again a `with open()` is better use here.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Try to implement their code using Python 2 syntax and the `file()` method. It is blatant that they are not using it here or even intending to. Nowhere in the above code block is the variable name `file` defined. They would further need to call `f = file('/path/', 'w')` then `f.write()`.

Comment: @pstatix: Never mind, it's okay, don't worry about it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Also, the fact that they use the word `file` in their code does not imply what version they are using. `with open('/path/', 'w') as file: file.write('Python3_Sytnax')`. CIP.

Comment: @pstatix: "Nowhere in the above code block is the variable name `file` defined."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152782/discussion-between-pstatix-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed to allocate the file pointer to file variable
Try this

```
from datetime import datetime
ctime = str(datetime.now())
try:
    with open("pyth_log.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write("pyth_log.txt")
        file.write("-------")
        file.write("LOG")
        file.write(ctime)
        file.write("-------")
except:
    print("Unable to open file")
```

Comment: It'd be good practice to encourage use of a context manager, ie. `with open("pyth_log.txt", "w") as file:` -- that also removes the need for an explicit `close()`, and avoids the bug where an exception anywhere *other* than the `open()` then skips the close (since the `except` block doesn't have one).

Comment: Please mark it as an answer

Comment: I attempted to but it told me to wait 10 minutes, I will when I can.

Comment: Really should be using `with open()`.

Comment: There are several other cleanups besides that other answers incorporate but this one doesn't -- deduplicating the `import`s, reducing the number of individual `write()` calls, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

ctime = str(datetime.now())
try:
    with open("pyth_log.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write("-------\n")
        file.write("LOG\n")
        file.write(ctime)
        file.write("\n-------\n")
except:
    print("Unable to open file")
    raise
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `write()` method, you must use with the file object. Also, it is better to use the `with open()` syntax over calling `close()` as the scope will be dropped when the `with` ends:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
ctime = str(datetime.now())
try:
    with open("pyth_log.txt", 'w') as f:
        file.write("pyth_log.txt\n"
                   "-------\n"
                   "LOG\n"
                   + ctime + "\n"
                   "-------")
except:
    print("Unable to open file")
    raise
```